# Calculadora en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una pequeña duda respecto a una calculadora grafica que estoy haciendo en java. Lo que pasa es que ya lo tengo todo hecho, pero hay un problema al pulsar el boton igual y operar todos los numeros. A continuacion les dejo el código:

```
    private void igualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    Double num = Double.parseDouble(pantalla.getText().substring(aux,pantalla.getText().length()));
    numeros.add(num);
    int iterador = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= operadores.size() - 1; i++) {
        switch(operadores.get(i)){
            case '+':
                resultado = resultado + (numeros.get(0) + numeros.get(1));
            case '-':
                resultado = resultado - numeros.get(iterador+1);
            case '*':
                resultado = resultado * numeros.get(iterador+1);
            case '/':
                resultado = resultado / numeros.get(iterador+1);
            iterador++;
        }        
     System.out.println(resultado);   
     System.out.println(numeros.get(0) + numeros.get(1));
    }  
}
```

Como pueden ver, dentro del for se hace todo el proceso de operaciones, el punto es que si os fijais, dentro del case para suma, guardo el resultado de sumar el indice 0 y 1 del ArrayList numeros en una variable llamada "resultado".

El problema es que la imprimo, y luego imprimo la suma directa y me salen dos resultados totalmente distintos, a continuacion os dejo lo que imprime la consola:

```
run:
10.0
20.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que como la variable resultado está en memoria, el valor que imprimirá será de la última operación que haya hecho en el switch, digo esto, porque no se cual es el orden que maneja la lista operadores.

Una solución para que sepas que valores toma "resultado" es que hagas impresiones por cada case algo así:

```
resultado = resultado + (numeros.get(0) + numeros.get(1));
System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);
break;
```

Recuerda siempre hacer un `break;` esto hace que ya no entre a otro caso diferente, ahí es donde también tu variable resultado cambia. Si entra a sumar, inmediatamente irá a restar, multiplicar, dividir, luego recién hará otra iteración.

Espero haberte ayudado en lo más mínimo.